# ASCII to Unicode conversion in doxygen blocks

Tags: doxygen

I'm using doxygen with Fortran. Apparently some Fortran compilers still have problems with Unicode strings, even in comments, so I have to keep all input as ASCII. No problem, I set `INPUT_ENCODING = ASCII` in the Doxyfile, and I can use some HTML entities like `&eacute;`. But I have some questions:

- The entities are maintained in the output (or converted to `\'{e}` in LaTeX). Can I have them converted to UTF-8 characters instead?
- It seems numerical entities `&#233;` or `&#x00e9;` are not recognized. Can I enter characters for which there is no named entity in some other way?